# How to Resize screen of Android

Tags: android, resize

I am developing an application for whole android devices. But resolation of screens are different and that is the biggest problem how it looks. So, I want to make resizing controls and also I used absolutelayout but It is still same.. I give value to controls as dp ..

How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: Never use AbsoluteLayout. Take a look at - http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/index.html

Comment: You cannot "resize" the screen. But what you want can be achieved by a different logic. Read Here: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: thanx guys.. I already read them... but I was thinking that there could be some resizing method or like that..

Answer (score 1):

You don't resize the screen of an android device - you make your app instead work with the various screen sizes.

The relevant docs are [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot hardcode the dimensions of your layout and expect it to work on every screen size. And there is no method which automatically does it unless you write it.

You might want to change your approach, use Relative Layout or Linear Layout instead and use values like `fill_parent` and `wrap_content` while designing your layout.

Another approach Android developers follow is use different resource files for different screen sizes and Android loads them automatically at runtime.

Refer to [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) for more info on how to work with different screen sizes effectively.